# Send emails in buildbot

Tags: email, gmail, buildbot

```
mn2 = MailNotifier(fromaddr="buildbot@example.org",
                   sendToInterestedUsers=False,
                   mode = 'all',
                   extraRecipients=['my@gmail.com'])
```

I tried using the above code to send email. But it does not send any notification to my gmail account. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing an important property, relayhost. Your log probably has errors in it from where it tries to send, but gets rejected. He're an example from one of my masters:

```
        buildbot.status.mail.MailNotifier(
            fromaddr = from_email,
            sendToInterestedUsers = False,
            extraRecipients = ['me@mydomain.com'],
            mode = 'change',
            relayhost = 'relay.mydomain.com')
```